# how to store return function value to a variable to use in original function in Django

Tags: django

I have two functions one calls the other to return a value seconds, I believe I have returned successfully however I need to now store it as a variable to use later on but have an error as per the following code:

```
def func2(request):
    try:

        user = User

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        startdate = str(user.start_date)
        startdate = startdate.rpartition('+')[0]
        startdate = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(startdate)
        timedelta = now - startdate

        seconds = timedelta.seconds
        print("This is seconds:", seconds)

        return seconds

    except Exception as e:
        pass


def func1(request):


        return func2(request)
        
        seconds = return func2(request) ### error - this does not work
```

Comment: It's better that you learn Python before learning Django

Comment: You are not returning a HttpResponse. That is the first issue.  If your want to assign a return value, do it like that `seconds = func2()`. Your exception clause does not return anything as well. If your want to fetch a return value of your func2(), your have to assign it to a paramter within `func1()`.

Comment: Actually my bad - the solution posted works - i had an issue with one of my strings. Thanks